# How to bake "CLAY DOH" nodes to make animation?

Tags: rendering, node-editor

I bought a Clay Doh nodes shader at blender market. The result is very nice, but this shader is basic on nodes. So I can't use it for animation. I saw his page said I can bake it as a bump map, but I didn't see Bump map.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since your shader is a commercial purchased one there is no way anyone here can see how your "Bump Map" output has been produced so I'm afraid we can't help you.

Comment: The documentation appears to be inaccurate, and is the responsibility of the author. You should contact them about this, not only for yourself, but for other customers. We can't help here, without stripping the product apart, so this question is off-topic. It does seem that plugging 'Displacement' into the height of a _Bump_ node might be a good bet.

Answer (score 1):

i think displacement map output is kinda close to bump map, so try baking it